# How to check if the Nested JSON values contains that column or not, using JAVA code

Tags: java, json

```
   {
   "Animals":[
   {
   "name":"parrot";
   },
   {
   "name":"lion";
   "type":"carnivours"
   },
   {
   "name":"cow";
   "type":"herbivours"
   }
   ]
   }
```

```
    if(Animals.has("type") && Animals.getString("type")!=null)
    {
    String type=clusters.get("type").toString(); 
    } 
    else 
    {
    String type=null; 
    }
```

Here in the above sample code all json doesnot contain the type column.
How to check if that Type column exists for all the json response and if not return null only for that column.

Comment: @Andreas Edited Please remove your negative comments. And Please help to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can define and Animal class as below with @JsonIgnoreProperties.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Animal{
    private String name;
    private String type;
}
```

Then you can define another class which will contain a list of animals. Then Jackson will map the JSON and then you can simply use not null check on Animal object.

Comment: Its not a class its a JSON response which I am fetching from an API

Comment: you can create the class on your side. How are you getting the JSON response please share .

Comment: {
   "Animals":[
   {
   "name":"parrot";
   },
   {
   "name":"lion";
   "type":"carnivours"
   },
   {
   "name":"cow";
   "type":"herbivours"
   }
   ]
   }

This is the sample JSON Response